# remove letters but leave numbers notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi is there a way with notepad++ to
remove all the letters from the text but leave numbers like this
pretty sample just remove letters and no numbers

example:

```
1. Bunch of text
1.1 Some more text.
1.2 Even more text.
New 2. text
2.1 New subtext
New sub-subtext 2.1.1
```

to became:

```
1. 
1.1 
1.2 
    2. 
2.1
                2.1.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "liters"?

Comment: I think OP meant "letters"

Comment: Why is it `1.1` and not `1.1.`?

Comment: Why is it `2.1.1` and not `-2.1.1`?

Comment: Sorry Meant "letters" and it's edited right now

Comment: Simply just removing letters and leave spaces and numbers as they are, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?|(.)
```

with

```
(?{1} :$0)
```

This replacement means "if you find a series of digits and periods starting with a digit, then use that, otherwise replace the character that you find with a space".

Here's a screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! it does the job exactly how it should be but, after applying, all my text  move to the first line!

Comment: @Firsthen Make sure you have unchecked the "`. matches newline`" checkbox.

Comment: If possible is there a way to keep "|" with the letters? @horcrux

Comment: @Firsthen I think you should open a new question.